# curser index out of bounds exception- imports wrong?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

My sqlite database does not work quite as it should, so in order to make sure I have the correct database, I tried to check the columns, using this:

```
Cursor c = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master       WHERE type=?",  new String[] {"table"});
 for (int i = 0; i <= c.getColumnCount(); i++){
    System.out.println(c.getString(i));}
```

Now, I had hopes that this would give me the names of all the columns in my database.
However, I run into a cursoroutofboundsexception.

Am I correct that this can only mean that my database does NOT have any columns and is therefore empty?

I CAN open the database in sqlite database browser, therefore something must be wrong with my imports - or is there a mistake with my code?

Can it be possible that my db somehow is not there and this is why it does not work?

I dumped my curser as suggested in the answer below.

Result:

```
 09-22 03:29:31.450: I/System.out(845): >>>>> Dumping cursor       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@b2dfd7a0
```

Now this is not exactly helpful.

Does that mean there is no database, for what reason whatsoever, or is the print somewhere else?

Ok that at least works, however the result is this:

```
 09-22 15:10:35.754: I/System.out(1095):    name=android_metadata
```

I wonder why there are no other columns though they are clearly in the database and I CAN open the file with a database browser.
Is this a typical mistake?

Comment: you have to move your Cursor to the first position: moveToFirst()

Comment: That sounds sensible but does not solve the problem.

Comment: I added c.moveToFirst() right before the loop - same Problem still.

Comment: You only have one column in your cursor resultset (`SELECT name`), but then you try to iterate all columns.  Also, **why** do you think you have the `wrong` database.  The database will be whatever you opened.

Comment: change i <= c.getColumnCount() to i < c.getColumnCount()

Comment: I will try that. However I wonder why , when I change to sqlite_master instead of sqlite_temp_master, I run into an IllegalStateException.  Also, what do you mean by I have only one? Does not the sql statement say: for each column, give me the name?

Comment: pskink, following your advice and changing the loop does not make any difference. And yes the db will be whatever I opened, but before I have not checked a query, how can I be REALLY sure that my db is fully there? First program with databases here....

Answer (score 1):

The typical idiom for iterating a cursor's rows is

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) { ... }
```

Column indexes are zero-based, so to iterate over the columns of a row, you would do

```
int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) { ... }
```

But if all you want to do is print out its contents, I would just pass the cursor off to [`DatabseUtils.dumpCursor(Cursor cursor)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor)).

**EDIT**

You should probably be selecting from `sqlite_master`, not `sqlite_temp_master`, as the latter only stores information about temporary tables and views.

Comment: If it only printed `">>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@(hash) (newline)<<<<<`, then your cursor was empty.